# Relations between multisets of irreducible factors when one element divides another in a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R$ be a UFD, and let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero elements of $R$. In a UFD all elements (other than $0$ and the units) determine a unique multiset (a set of elements "with multiplicity") of irreducible factors. We can also agree that units have no factors; that is, the corresponding multiset is $\varnothing$.

I'm in the process of proving that

> - $(a) \subseteq (b) \Leftrightarrow $ the multiset of irreducible factors of $b$ is contained in the multiset of irreducible factors of $a$
> - $(a) = (b) \Leftrightarrow$ the two multisets coincide

It's pretty straightforward if $a$ or $b$ is a unit (if $a$ is a unit, $(a) = R \subseteq (b)$, then so is $b$, and $\varnothing = \varnothing$, if $b$ is a unit, $\varnothing$ is contained in any multiset).
$(a) \subseteq (b) \Leftrightarrow a \in (b) \Leftrightarrow \exists c \in R: \ a = bc$

It's easy if $c$ is not a unit, so it has a factorization into irreducibles.

Let $q_1...q_n, q'_1...q'_m, q''_1...q''_r$ be the respective factorizations of $a, b, c$. And so on.

But what if $c$ **is** a unit? It cannot be factorized into irreducibles. So we have

$q_1...q_n = cq'_1...q'_m$

What does it really tells us about relations between $\{q_1, ..., q_n \}$ and $\{q'_1, ..., q'_m \}$?

Answer (score 1):

If $c$ is a unit and $a=bc,$ then $b=a(c^{-1})$. So $b\in (a),$ which means $(b)\subseteq (a).$ Therfor $(b)=(a).$ Now use uniqueness of multiset in a UFD.

Comment: Yes, I know that $(a) = (b) \Leftrightarrow a = ub$ for some unit $u$ in an integral domain $R$. Still, how does it help us? That $(a) = (b)$